# Exporting my .NET 7 WinForms app to Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, mono

For a project, I build a WinForms application using .NET 7.0. I noticed it must run on Linux so I made some research and found that it's possible to run .NET code with mono but it's not applicable to WinForms. Is there a solution to convert my project without having to make the design of the forms from scratch (like would be the case with mono development)?

Thanks.

What I tried: Installing mono and running my code. It says me that no CLI image was found.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea Unless you are comfortable to support yourself, you should avoid WinForms on Mono.

Answer (score 3):

No cross-platform desktop GUI exists in .NET out of the box.

To overcome this issue Microsoft created [MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui#xamarinforms-vs-net-maui) although it was announced Linux devices won't get official support.

Your best bet would be to migrate to [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/) or [UNO](https://platform.uno/), both are great open-source, free and feature-rich frameworks built on top of .NET which works on any operating system, including Ubuntu, macOS and Windows.
Both frameworks use XAML dialect which should feel familiar for developers coming from WPF, UWP, or Xamarin Forms.

UNO can be developed using [C# markup](https://uno-website-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/11142217/CSharp_Markup.webm) instead XAML

> No XAML needed if you don’t want it – Enjoy a Flutter-like
> UI development experience with C# and .NET Hot Reload
> by using C# for Markup

Comment: I looked at Avalonia it seems to pretty do what I expect, thanks a lot !

Comment: @NicolasBzn Feel free to approve my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Only .NET 7 console app runs (through .NET 7 runtime) on Linux, no WinForms, no WPF.

If you need a .NET desktop app running on Linux, and you are targeting GNOME desktop environment, you could give a try to [gtk#](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp) based on mono.

Comment: You'd better point to the latest GTK#, https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp

Comment: That's right, done.